# select parts out of a DataArray created with xarray (python)

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, python-xarray

```
    ds = xr.open_dataset(f)
    hlos = ds.rayleigh_hloswind_windresult_rayleigh_wind_velocity.data
    lats = ds.rayleigh_geolocation_windresult_geolocation_latitude_cog.data 

>>> hlos
array([  419., -1013.,  -584., ..., -6791., 32767., 32767.], dtype=float32)
>>> lats
array([84.36244 , 84.359972, 84.371422, ..., 83.43806 , 83.672662,
       83.513285])
```

f is a netcdf file with the variable hlos which is the wind velocity and lats which is the latitude. I created a DataArray:

```
da_lat = xr.DataArray(hlos, dims=['lat'], coords = {'lat': lats})
>>> da_lat
<xarray.DataArray (lat: 19703)>
array([  419., -1013.,  -584., ..., -6791., 32767., 32767.],
      dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float64 84.36 84.36 84.37 ... 83.67 83.51
```

Now I would like to select like: `da_lat.sel(lat = 84.36).values`, but this gives me a KeyError:84.36
Does anyone knoe what's the problem in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `KeyError` is a result of the fact that there is not an *exact* match for the latitude 84.36 in the latitude coordinate.  The exact match looks like it would be 84.36244 (or perhaps 84.359972).  Xarray offers a nice way of working around this, as you can specify a `method` in the `sel` method which controls how it deals with inexact matches.

In this case it looks like you might want something like `method='nearest'`:

```py
da_lat.sel(lat=84.36, method='nearest')
```

See the [documentation for `Dataset.sel`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.sel.html#xarray.Dataset.sel) for more details.